# Java -why can't I set a value in an array to null after I return it?

Tags: java

I'm returning a value from an array, but I want to set the value to null afterwards .  The problem is I keep getting an error.  Why is this?

```
public Book retrieveBookFromBookshelf (String title)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < this.books.length; i++) {
     if (this.books[i].getTitle().equals(title)) {
        return this.books[i];
        this.books[i] = null;
     }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Once your program reads and processes the `return` statement, it will never reach the line below it since control of the program is `return`ed to the calling method.

Answer (score 3):

Because before you set the value to null, you return from the function. Once return is executed, nothing else is done  in the current function and control is given back to the caller function.

Answer (score 2):

What you're attempting to do is not possible. instead, cache the reference to `this.books[i]`.

```
if (this.books[i].getTitle().equals(title)) {
       Book book = this.books[i]; // cache the reference
       this.books[i] = null;
       return book;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't normally run statements after returning. You need to store the value in a temporary variable:

```
Book result = this.books[i];
this.books[i] = null;
return result;
```

Alternatively, you can return in a `try` block and set it to null inside `finally`:

```
try {
    return this.books[i];
} finally {
    this.books[i] = null;
}
```

But I think that's a little overkill for your use case.

Comment: "*Alternatively, you can return in a `try` block and set it to `null` inside `finally`*" - What could possibly go wrong? =)

Comment: @Turing85 What are you implying?

Comment: That this kind of code is asking for trouble in the future. It is error-prone and hard to understand. Just because it is possible does not mean it should be used =)